# How to find the limit $ \lim_{x\to 0} [x^2]/x^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I mean to say
 how to find the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{[x^2]}{x^2}$?
where $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer function of $x$.

Comment: Isn't the answer just 0. Am I overthinking?!

Answer (score 4):

For $|x|<1$, we know that $[x^2]=0$.  Thus, we have

$$\frac{[x^2]}{x^2}=0\text{ when }|x|<1,x\ne0$$

So the limit is obviously $0$.

Comment: how can we say that |x|<1 implies [x^2]=1?

Comment: @s.panja No, it is equal to $0$.  Clearly, since $[0.1^2]=0$, $[0.9^2]=0$, etc.

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Comment: but what about the value of the function in a nbd of 0?

Comment: @s.panja Identitically $0$, always.

Comment: yah thanks@simple art

Comment: @s.panja No problem, glad to clear up the problems!

Comment: @SimpleArt: so it is that tricky situation when both left and right limits at $x=a$ exist, but $f(a)$ does not

Comment: @Alex Clearly division by $0$ has that yes